# How to automatically fill a formula, to the length of the table, in the next column?

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have one table placed in range A5:F (the length of this table is changing when I refresh this table, so one time is 7k~ rows and other time is about 5k~ rows).

After refresh table (for example let's say the table range is A5:F7000) I have to select cells G5;H5;I5 and copy these and fill this down to the length of table. In the cells G5;H5;I5 I have formulas.

I don't have a VBA code for this because I don't have any idea how to solve this.

Comment: How do you refresh the table? Do you know how many rows the refresh will result into, programmatically ?

Comment: No, it’s unknown, because I refresh sales data via provider placed in excel (provider is from SAP Business Object). Every time I refresh this data the number of rows is changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fill Down Formulas

- [`FillDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.filldown)
- s - Source, d - Destination

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub fillDownFormulas()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sCols As String = "A:F"
    Const dCols As String = "G:I"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 5
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sCols).Rows(FirstRow)
        Dim sCell As Range
        Set sCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
           .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = sCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Dim drg As Range
        Set drg = .Worksheet.Columns(dCols).Rows(FirstRow).Resize(rCount)
        drg.FillDown
        drg.Resize(.worksheet.Rows.count - .Row - rCount + 1) _
            .Offset(rCount).Clear
    End With
     
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I looked for! Thank you so much for your help!